# Nothing display in IBM MobileFirst Operations Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm build an app by using MobileFirst Platform in Eclipse. When i run app by click runAs >> Run On MobileFirst Development Server, the console in eclipse say that:  Application "myapp" with all environments build finished. But when i use browser to direct localhost:10080/worklightconsole, the worklightconsole appear but nothing display on the console. I don't know what the reason. Can any one explain for me!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHwwZ.png)

Comment: I think you may need to clear your cache. Also try in a different browser.

Comment: restart your eclipse or restart your server then open different browser better if you restart your pc .

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot looks suspiciously like a browser problem.

Try clearing the browser cache or using a different browser and see if the problem persists.